# prevent gcc from searching the current dir "-I-" option on include search path

Tags: c++, search, gcc, path, include

Our dev environment makes heavy use of directories with locally modified headers that should be seen by the compiler instead of the "committed" "repository" versions.

If header A includes header B, gcc looks for B in the same directory A was in and does not obey the seach path.
So we used the `-I-` option on gcc to prevent that. Gcc will strictly follow the hierarchy of the include-path then.
As with gcc4 the `-I-` option is deprecated and repaced by `-iqoute`.
I can't figure out how to get the same behaviour with the `-iquote` option because I think it is lacking the side-effect of disabling the search in the "current" directory.

see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html#Invocation

Any ideas how to achieve the same behaviour?

Answer (score 10):

AFAIK, there is no other way to desactivate the behaviour you are complaining about other than using the form `#include <foo.h>` instead of `#include "foo.h"` in your code.

ISTR, but I've failed to find a reference, that the rationale for deprecating `-I-` without providing another mechanism for that aspect is that libraries commonly use the form `#include "foo.h"` to ensure they get their own internal header file `foo.h` and the use of `-I-` broke them in some cases if someone else happened to have a file similarly named earlier on the search path.